# Background Execution in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I have an app that has some background execution on beacon,- and geo-enter and exit events. At beacon Exit event I have a timer or around 8 seconds for example. Everything worked fine in iOS 9. In iOS 10 however the Background Execution Time seems very random. Sometimes it works sometimes it does not.
I´m aware of the 10 Seconds Limit.

Is anybody also experiencing the same? I can´t find any new rule in the Apple Documentation.

Many Thanks
Stephan

Comment: Can you show your code. Are you calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`?

Comment: `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` did the trick! Thanks! Still since iOS 10 some Beacon Exit Events are not getting called..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try it but if I'd you I would look into `UIApplication.sharedApplication().backgroundTimeRemaining`